input sequence error in python code loading weights of textgenrnn
import numpy as np
import h5py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Input
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

# Load weights from HDF5 file
def load_weights_from_hdf5(hdf5_file):
  with h5py.File(hdf5_file, 'r') as f:
    weights = []
    for layer_name in f.keys():
      print("Layer Name:", layer_name)
      layer_group = f[layer_name]
      print("Layer Group:", layer_group)
      layer_weights = []
      for weight_name in layer_group.keys():
        print("Weight Name:", weight_name)
        weight_values = layer_group[weight_name].values
        print("Weight Values:", weight_values)
        layer_weights.append(weight_values)
      weights.append(layer_weights)
    return weights


# Define your LSTM model
def create_lstm_model(input_shape, num_classes):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Input(shape=input_shape))
    model.add(LSTM(128))
    model.add(LSTM(128))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
    return model

# Load pre-trained weights
weights_file = r'D:\PYcharm projects\DATASETS\textgenrnn_weights.hdf5'
loaded_weights = load_weights_from_hdf5(weights_file)

# Assuming input shape and number of classes
input_shape = (100, 128) # Assuming input sequences of alength 100 with 1 feature
num_classes = 128  # Assuming 128 different characters

# Create LSTM model
model = create_lstm_model(input_shape, num_classes)

# Set weights of LSTM model
model.set_weights(loaded_weights)

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])



Error:
024-05-23 20:39:58.577328: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PYcharm projects\NLP\model textgenrnn.py", line 43, in <module>
    model = create_lstm_model(input_shape, num_classes)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\PYcharm projects\NLP\model textgenrnn.py", line 30, in create_lstm_model
    model.add(LSTM(128))
  File "D:\PYcharm projects\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\sequential.py", line 120, in add
    self._maybe_rebuild()
  File "D:\PYcharm projects\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\sequential.py", line 139, in _maybe_rebuild
    self.build(input_shape)
  File "D:\PYcharm projects\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\layer.py", line 223, in build_wrapper
    original_build_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\PYcharm projects\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\sequential.py", line 183, in build
    x = layer(x)
        ^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\PYcharm projects\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 122, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "D:\PYcharm projects\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\input_spec.py", line 186, in assert_input_compatibility
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "lstm_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 128)

I want to load weights file of textgenrnn hdf5 file to train model of lstm to generate text, but input sequence error.
